# FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am in big trouble with firestore.
here there is a link for the code sources: https://github.com/10100011001/10100011001.github.io/tree/master/public/assets/scripts

Model:

```
self.saveData = function(input) { 
    let userInfo = {
      username : input.value,
      userScore : self.settings.playerScore,
    };
    let userStr = JSON.stringify(userInfo);
    localStorage.setItem('user', userStr);
    let name = input.value,
        score = self.settings.playerScore;
    myAppDB.collection('results').doc(`player_${name.replace(/\s/g, "").toLowerCase()}`).set({
      player: `${name}`,
      score: `${score}`,
    })
    .then(function() {
      console.log('result saved');
     })
     .catch(function(error) {
      console.log('error saving result: ', error);
    });
    myView.clearInput(input);
    myView.closeModal();
  };
```

Controller:

```
self.saveData = function() {  // сохраняем данные из инпута
  let input = myControllerContainer.querySelector('#playerName');
  myModel.saveData(input);
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: That will be a problem with your firebase rules not with your code: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoted from your comment:

> these are my [security] rules ... `allow read, write: if false`

Since you said `if false`,

- that condition will never be true,
- hence your security rules will not allow you to write to your database from the front end.

You could

1. use the Admin SDK in a backend Cloud Function to do the write, or
2. change the rule.

Edit:

Please note that while it is convenient to set your read write rules to `if true` during development, that means that anyone can access your database!

I highly recommend reading the documentation on Firestore security rules, and, as soon as you have anything important in your database, developing rules to reflect appropriate access levels for yourself, your team, and your end users, registered and unregistered.

Docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/overview

Comment: @10100011001 You are quite welcome! Please note the edit in my answer regarding "if true."

Answer (score 1):

The error message you get means that your application is trying to read or write some data that you don't have access to.

All data access to Cloud Firestore is controlled by Firebase's server-side [security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/overview), which ensure that each user can only access data they're authorized for.

To get rid of this error you need to find the exact code that is generating it. You then have two options:

1. Modify the security rules to allow the operation.
2. Modify the code to stay within what the security rules allow.

Neither of these is pertinently better than the other. It all depends on the use-cases and business rules of your application.

I recommend that you read the documentation on business rules I linked above, and then also study this additional [guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules). With that information you should be able to fix the problem.

If you have concrete problems after this, post a question with the [minimal security rules, data, and code with which anyone can reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and we can try to help further.

Comment: I still don't get this(

this are my rules :

rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if false;
    }
  }
}

at Authentication, everything is enabled because of none of those fit me; I dont need to use any password, im just trying to read and save information from input(user name) thats it

Comment: you have `allow read, write: if false` --> since you said `if false`, that will never be true, hence your security rules will not allow you to write to your database from the front end.  You could, however, use the admin SDK in a backend cloud function to do the write, or you could change the rule